# Creation of Bootable Windows ISO Image

Tags: iso

Kindly, if somebody can help me how to create a bootable iso image from CD/DVD (Windows DVD)

Thank you

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CreateIsoFromCDorDVD